# What are the practical uses of bit-fields in language C?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I'm reading a tutorial of C (in french), and in a paragraph they talk about bit-fields, and they gave the following example without much explanation :

```
struct register {
   unsigned int mask : 3;
   signed int privilege : 6;
   unsigned int : 6; /* not used */
   unsigned int ov : 1;
};
```

1. What is the result of this definition at memory level?
2. Is there any pedagogical reason to have named the structure `register` in the example (this reminds me of electronics)?
3. Why would someone declare a member like the one commented by "not used" in the example?
4. What are the benefits of this structure in practice?
5. Why doesn't a bits field have an address? Does this match to a specification in a Register?

Comment: They aren't so usefull on PC as on MCU.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Can you tell me why?

Comment: Usually you have a lot of memory on your PC. Also operations with bit flags are more slowly than operations with byte flags. That's why on PC you usually use byte (uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t or even uint64_t) flags. But CPU's have very little memory. Also many of them can work with single bits. That's why on CPU you usually make bit flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is especially useful in the Hardware where you want to create a Register of a module.

Now, `Register` has many `bit-fields` in it which can be of varying size in `bits`.
So, you create a structure to represent the `Register` and the `bit-fields`. Basically registers in hardware are the structures  which store the information about the module.

For Ex, for USB module the registers inside the USB hardware store the information about the status of the USB device and many other things.

By limiting  the length of data members inside the `struct` to `bits` instead of reserving `uints(or any other primitive data types)` for  the `bit-fields` as it occupies very less memory.

Also, the dummy declaration  `unsigned int : 6;` is used to pad the structure so that the structure objects and the accesses are `word aligned` according to the machine architecture. Hence the access to the register objects doesn't consume more time if the accesses are aligned to the word boundary of the processor. Basically if the word, half-word or a byte is aligned at the address which is the multiples of the processor's word size then it is accessible very efficiently at a single stretch.

For example, in your case the `Register` is of `16-bits` and it has 3 bit-fields: mask, privilege and ov. Whereas the remaining `6-bits` are reserved for future use. 
Here it is how `Register` looks like,

```
bit-position     15  14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
                ---------------------------------------
                |ov |    reserved    | privilege |mask|
                ---------------------------------------
```

So, by making the structure of size 16-bits the objects of this structure can be easily accessible on a processor with 8,16,32 .... bit ALU's

Comment: Pretty nice explanation, :) , I thumb up! thanks for this effort! However, I have some questions : 1/ I didn't really get what u meant by "word aligned". 2/ I expected that a register of 16 bits can be accessible for 8 or 16 bit ALU only,... how comes even 32 is possible? 3/ I made an Edit and I added question 5/. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: It is possible for `32 bit` also, because `16-bit` is the half-word on 32-bit architecture. So, while accessing if this `16-bit` data is present on the lower 2-bytes or higher 2-bytes in the `32bit` word then what happens is, the whole word(`32-bit`) is accessed and the unwanted bytes either higher `2-bytes` or lower `2-bytes` are chopped off and correct data is returned back. 
For more information of the word alignment please refer to this link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/pa-dalign/

Comment: Very nice link! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Bitfields would be nice for things like hardware registers if their behavior were actually categorized meaningfully.  As it is, I'm not really sure what is gained by saying much more than "implementations do whatever they want" with bitfields of the present form, and defining a new syntax to explicitly alias an identifier with a variable or field in the same scope, which would occupy a certain bit range in the latter [e.g. within an "I/O port" structure, `PIN3_OPTS := OPTREG0:12:4;` would make `PIN3_OPTS` refer to bits 12-15 of `OPTREG0`].  Code that works on a particular compiler...

Comment: ...would continue to do so, and future code written using the new standard would be portable among compilers that follow it.

Answer (score 1):

One example of where a structure like the one in the question could be used, is to emulate the bits of a hardware *register* (which is the likely use of this structure judging by the name).

For many small and embeddable systems, there may be hardware registers directly addressable in memory, and so structures such as these can be used to access bits directly in these registers.